# how to trigger a set commands when user setfocus on a text box in a website using c#

Tags: textbox, focus

i have a username textbox and a password textbox in the webpage.

i want username textbox to read the following code once it has lost focused/ when the user clicks on the password textbox? so that the password is automatically displayed in the password text box.

```
    String cookiename = usernameTextBox.Text;

    //grab cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[cookiename];

    //exists?
    if (null == cookie)
    {
        Label1.Text = "cookie not found";
    }
    else
    {
        passwordTextBox.Attributes.Add("value", cookie.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Focus is the only thing available i found, i knw its similar but i cant seem to figure it out.

thanks,

Comment: I think the opposite of "focus" is called "blur": http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onblur.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

One, **why are you storing the user's password in plain text in a cookie? That's extremely unsafe!** This is so fundamentally insecure that **you might as well not have passwords**. There are plenty of ways to handle this. Here's one simple example:

If you want the site to "remember" the user's password, generate a unique token (such as a GUID) and store the GUID alongside their account info on the server as the "active session", and store the GUID in the cookie. When the user visits the site, check to see if the token cookie exists and if so, you can match that up with the user's login info on the server side and bypass the login page altogether. There are additional things to take into consideration, but that's the basic concept.

Two, your current design requires an AJAX-like callback. The code you've written in c# runs on the server, but the focus/blur events happen on the client side.

From a purely technical perspective, you should write JavaScript to handle this entire process. A JS function can run `onblur()` and JS can read cookies just as well as .NET can:

```
var usernameBox = document.getElementById('usernameBox');
usernameBox.onblur = handleBlur;

function handleBlur() {
    var passwordBox = document.getElementById('passwordBox');
    passwordBox.value = readCookie(cookieName);
}

function readCookie(cookieName) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

(Note that `getElementById` uses the **client ID**, and not the ASP.NET ID)

Your security issue is a much bigger problem. There is no way to fix what you're trying to accomplish; it's just fundamentally a bad idea.

Comment: hi, thanx for reply, im working on a simple prototype and i have to simply show the process. ;)
where iam supposed to put this code? sorry im not that good in programming yet!!

Comment: I added the relevant code to attach the handleBlur() function to the textbox's blur event.